# creating a crystal parameter from a formula output

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

In my report there is a Purchasing Group number with values like 100,101,102....201,202,203..301,302,303... etc.
There is a formula to identify the Purchasing group department -

If {PURGRP} startswith '1'
    then 'Purchasing Dept.'
else
if {PURGRP} startswith '2'
    then 'Construction Agreements Office'
else
if {PURGRP} startswith '3'
    then 'Storerooms'
else......

The report is grouped by these departments. i am trying to create a parameter which allows the user to select the Department by the names in the formula, but i am not able to append these names to available values as they are derived from a formula. One option is hard coding the values, but I was hoping there could be a more dynamic way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought was to capture all the department names in shared array, but I don't see any way to attach that to the parameter.

In all likelihood, having a separate lookup table in your main database is the simplest and least error-prone path.  I suppose you could write a maketable query that would make your lookup table dynamic, but Crystal Reports isn't built for this purpose.

Comment: Yes you are right, I did it on my database query level, works fine. Thanks